# Location of python packages in a venv on linux

Tags: linux, python-venv

I'm running into some issues trying to run my python script in a venv. I created a python3 venv in the directory of where my script is located - `/home/username/myproject/venv` . When I activate my venv and install all of my packages the script requires they are then installed at `/myproject/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages` However, when I run my script it DOES NOT work. If I move my packages into the actual project folder where the actually script is located then my script works.

Why is my script not picking up the packages/modules that are located in `(venv) myvm:~/myproject/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages`?

Comment: How do you run your script?

Comment: I use PM2 - so I activate my venv, cd to where my script is located, then `pm2 start myscript.py`

Comment: Sorry, I don't know PM2? Do you have a link, or a full name?

Comment: It is likely your problem: whatever executable `pm2` is, it is probably not in your venv, and thus `pm2` and the related Python executable are those outside of your venv.

Comment: That makes sense! does that mean pm2 needs to be installed in every new venv?

Comment: Probably. Or there is some configuration option so that you can point `pm2` to the correct Python executable. (Or you can try and avoid `pm2` altogether, but that may not be an option.)

Comment: correct - using it to run my script 24/7